# RegEx: Replace string between two non-matching strings

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace a word in a string:

> Input: "left.position.left = leftContent.left.posleft"
>
> Output: "a.position.left = content.left.posleft"

Before "left" there shouldn´t be [a-zA-Z0-9.] and behind there shouldn´t be [a-zA-Z0-9].

This is my code I wrote so far:

```
"left.position.left = leftContent.left.posleft".replace(new RegExp("left(?![a-zA-Z0-9])", "g"), "a")
```

But it returns:

> "a.position.a = leftContent.a.posa"

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])left
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `$1a`.

https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/24

```
var re = /(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])left/gi;
var str = 'left.position.left = leftContent.left.posleft';
var subst = '$1a';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Oh, it works fine. Thank you! I used:
var re = new RegExp("(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9.])left(?![a-zA-Z0-9])", "gi");

Comment: @Martin https://regex101.com/r/tJ2mW5/25 its working fine here.see .The one you proposed will not replace `leftContent`